# Creating a labeled build with Jenkins, Maven & SVN

Tags: svn, maven, jenkins

I created a parameterized job in Jenkins that:

- Gets sources based on label "V_x_y_z" (Jenkins-SVN integration)
- Executes Maven passing the label
- POM uses build-helper-maven-plugin to calculate version x.y.z

The resulting artifact is correct, BUT has the wrong version.

I see no way to change the resulting POM version except passing the version in the command line to versions-maven-plugin. But Jenkins has no way of parsing the label and transforming it into a version.

So it seems there are only "bad" options:

1. Demand user enter both build and label - **error prone**
2. Perform the checkout in Maven, not jenkins - this **breaks separation of concerns**, as POM itself is a versioned item.
3. Wrap maven with a script (say python) - but then I **lose the benefits of Jenkins-Maven integration**

I would have thought this is a banal use case, and easily supported - am I missing some key ingredient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best approach to achieve that would be to run 2 pre build steps:

1. Invoke a shell script that creates a java property file with the manipulated version

   echo "MYVERSION=$LABEL" | sed -e 's/_/./g' > new_property_file.properties
2. Invoke EnvInject plugin step that reads that property file and inject the newly created env var

After that you could invoke maven plugin with the new env var as input to the maven command.